# Amazon Elastic Beanstalk Content Management

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have created my Elastic Beanstalk application with Wordpress to test.  However I am struggling to understand the best way of managing changes in dynamic content online and development changes locally.

1. I upload my initial Wordpress Installation to my AWS Bucket
2. I run the initial Wordpress Setup
3. -- Lets presume that I have included a live theme and uploaded some products and time has progress, changes are made online, new products added to WooCommerce etc..
4. I make a new page template locally and want to upload to the Bucket
5. I use EB Deploy, but when I do this all content online in my Bucket is overwritten with the local content.

Now I do of course accept this is by design, but how is the problem best addressed?

Does anyone have any advice to offer with managing content of this sort in the AWS EB?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deploying WordPress on Elastic Beanstalk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12477828/deploying-wordpress-on-elastic-beanstalk)

Answer (score 2):

The instances managed by EB have to be considered disposable. This means that they can disappear without notice.

If the changes are dynamic (eg: files are being uploaded) you cannot store those files in the file system of the instances as they are disposable.

In addition, have in mind that if you scale to several instances, you will have different instances managing different data sets (eg: you upload a file to only one instance, not to all of them).

There are several approaches you can try, for example:

- Use a Network File System (NFS) server: in a separate instance, setup a NFS server and set up the EB instances to mount a remote mountpoint at startup. With this approach you can centralize the storage for all your EB instances.
- Check out the EFS service from AWS. It's like a NFS server but Amazon flavored. Haven't checked it out yet but it looks promising.

Comment: So essentially you create a \wp-content\uploads mount point to another storage instance, then when the data is refreshed or deployed, the mount point would remain untouched?  EFS is not available in Ireland as yet.

Comment: Yes, thats it. That way, if the EB instance disappear the data persists.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12477828/deploying-wordpress-on-elastic-beanstalk?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

To resolve these problems I created a couple of extra S3 buckets, the first for images and the second for css, js and alike.

Since this was a Wordpress, WooCommerce installation, I commissioned the S3 Offload plugin from Delicious Brains (https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-offload-s3/) ehich was a little expensive but this moved and monitored content of this sort and copied off to the other S3 buckets and allowed the 'EB Deploy' to leave the working content untouched.